# Any updates or improvements with Solr search in SDL Web 8?

Tags: web8, search

When upgrading to SDL Web 8 are there any re-index scripts or other maintenance scripts that would be advised to run on the search collection?

Are there any improvements or updates made to the Solr powered search in SDL Web 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were some minor changes like:

1. Java 8 support for SOLR
2. some of the jars were updated in order to enable *.mp4 files indexing

Answer (score 2):

The search collection should be optimized regularly to maintain and improve system performance, as described in the documentation here (especially post large content imports):

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-C198F223-D118-4B43-A225-6305361F77D5

More SOLR specific maintenance tasks are available here:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages